# Exit value from cscript cached in batch file?

Tags: javascript, batch-file, wsh

I need to fire off some javascript and return results to a batch file. I'm using the cscript command to do so. It works as expected on each runs of the batch file, but if I put the call to cscript in a loop, the return value seems to get cached while the batch file is running. Here is the problem stripped down to it's essence:

demo.bat:

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 5) do (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "demo.js" %%i
    echo %%i returned: %Errorlevel%
)
```

demo.js:

```
WSH.Quit(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
```

output:

```
C:\temp>demo.bat
1 returned 9
2 returned 9
3 returned 9
4 returned 9
5 returned 9

C:\temp>demo.bat
1 returned 55
2 returned 55
3 returned 55
4 returned 55
5 returned 55
```

So each loop iteration echoes the same number, but it does change when you re-run the batch file. I would expect it to change on every iteration. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In batch script, lines or block of lines (lines enclosed in parenthesis) are first parsed, then executed and the process continues to the next line/block. During the parse phase, all variable reads are removed from code and replaced with the value inside the variable **before** starting to execute.

That means that if inside a block the value of a variable is changed, this changed value can not be retrieved because there is no read operation to retrieve the value in the variable.

In your case, you have two options: use delayed expansion or change errorlevel check syntax

With delayed expansion enabled you can change the variable access sintax from `%var%` to `!var!`, indicating to the parser that the variable expansion (access to the value in the variable) must be delayed until the execution phase.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

for /l %%i in (1, 1, 5) do (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "demo.js" %%i
    echo %%i returned: !Errorlevel!
)
```

The other option is to use the syntax `if errorlevel x ...`. Not very useful with your code sample returning random values, but with a known set of values it should be

```
@echo off
for /l %%i in (1, 1, 5) do (
    cscript /nologo /e:jscript "demo.js" %%i
    if error level 10 (
       ....
    ) else if errorlevel 9 (
       .....
    )
    if errorlevel 8 ....
    ....
    if not errorlevel 1 (
       ....
    )
)
```

In this case, errorlevel must be checked from higher values to lower values, as the test `if errorlevel n` will be true for any value greater or equal to `n`

Comment: Perfect - thanks. An easy solution and an excellent explanation. Cheers!